# PHP Registration Script Saying All Fields Are Required when All are filled

Tags: php, mysql, registration

The following script does not function as it should.  When I go to it on my website and type in all the fields, it still says 'All fields are required'.  I modified it a bit from a script on this website: http://www.abell12.com/ .  You have to register to be able to download it but once you do, click on Scripts, then PHP, then go to Login And Registration and download the script.  Here is my version of the script :

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password1']);

    $enc_password = md5($password);

    if($name && $username && $password && $password1)
    {
        if(strlen($name)<30)
        {
            if(strlen($username)<10)
            {
                if(strlen($password)<30 || strlen($password)>6)
                {
                    if($password == $password1)
                    {
                        require "dbc.php";
                        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$name','$username','$enc_password')");
                        echo "Registration Complete! <a href='loginpage.php'>Click here to login</a>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Passwords must match";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "Your password must be between 6 and 30 characters";   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Your username is too long";   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Your name is too long";
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        echo "All fields are required"; 
    }
}

?>

<html>

    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){echo "$name";} ?>"> Max Length:30<p>
        Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ echo "$username";} ?>"> Max Length:15<p>
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"> Max length:30<p>
        Re-Enter Password: <input type="password" name="password1"><p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register">
    </form>

</html>
```

If you need more information, feel free to ask me.

Comment: Please echo before the if condition :- echo $name.'&&'.$username.'&&'.$password.'&&'.$password1;exit; and check whether every fields are getting posted or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error with this line:

```
if($name && $username && $password && $password1)
```

You'll need to use `empty`:

```
if(empty($name) && empty($username) && empty($password) && empty($password1))
```

As from the literal meaning `empty()` means variable is empty. It's a BOOL function, which means that it will return `true` when empty and `false` when not empty.

**Tip**: You should not use MySQL as it is already deprecated, use MySQLi instead.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful answer.  I still have to wait till I can call this the answer.

Comment: @SkrillexNukehulk You're welcome! Glad to have helped!

Comment: I hate to say this but, I have this same problem again after I modified the script a bit.  Are you willing to help me?

Comment: @SkrillexNukehulk What changes have you made?

Comment: I fixed the problem by getting rid of the empties.

Answer (score 0):

You use as optimiz code like this.

use below

```
if($name!='' && $username!='' && $password!='' && $password1!='')
```